# How to split sentences from multiple txt files while keeping track from which paragraph it is from and its position in the paragraph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text

I’m stuck with the following problem. I’m trying to split sentences of multiple text files while keeping track of which paragraph it’s from and its position in the paragraph. What I mean with position is if it’s for example the first, second, or last sentence. In addition, I want to omit duplicates while keeping track of how many they are in the same paragraph and on the same position. All text files use one format and have the same number of paragraphs. What I’m aiming for is this:

| SENTENCE | PARAGRAPH | POSITION | OCCURENCES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sentence_A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Sentence_B | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| Sentence_C | 2 | 1 | 1 |

I managed to count all occurrences using the following code.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import re

my_dir_path = "data/text_files/"
sentences = []
for file in Path(my_dir_path).iterdir():
with open(file, 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as file_open:
    string = file_open.read()
    string = re.sub(r"\n+", '\n', string)   
    string = re.sub(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', r"\1:\2", string)   
    string = string.replace('\n', ' ')   
    string = string.replace('. ', '.')   
    string = string.split('.')
    
    for elem in string:
        if 'Verwachting vandaag en morgen:' in elem: # omit specific sentence
            continue
        else:
            sentences.append(elem)
            
df = pd.DataFrame(sentences, columns=['SENTENCES'])
df1 = df['SENTENCES'].value_counts().rename('SENTENCES').reset_index(name='OCCURENCES')
```

Adding the conditional part about the paragraph and its position is where I got stuck. I’m a novice at Python, any pointers are appreciated :]

Example text: https://pastebin.com/y30hzWCB. It always has 2 newlines between paragraphs. Some sentences are cut off in-between with a newline.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import re
from collections import defaultdict

my_dir_path = "data/text_files/"
data = {"SENTENCE": [], "PARAGRAPH": [], "POSITION": [], "OCCURENCES": []}

for file in Path(my_dir_path).iterdir():
    parano = 1
    pos = 0
    already = False
    occ = defaultdict(int)
    
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as file_open:
        string = file_open.read()
        string = re.sub(r"\n+", '\n', string)
        string = re.sub(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', r"\1:\2", string)
        string = string.replace('\n', ' ')
        string = string.replace('. ', '.')
        string = string.split('.')
    
        for elem in string:
            if elem == "\n" and already:
                parano += 1
                already = True
                pos = 0
            else:
                already = False
                pos += 1
    
            if 'Verwachting vandaag en morgen:' in elem:  # omit specific sentence
                continue
            elif elem not in data["SENTENCES"]:
                data["SENTENCE"].append(elem)
                data["PARAGRAPH"].append(parano)
                data["POSITION"].append(pos)
                occ[elem] = 1
            else:
                occ[elem] += 1
    
    for i in data["SENTENCES"]:
        data["OCCURENCES"].append(occ[i])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I did:

- created a dictionary `data` which would directly be used to create the required dataframe
- kept count of paragraph number `parano` by checking if current line is a newline
- kept count of position by simply increasing `pos` each time a valid sentence occured